# Retrieve element value

Tags: jquery

I would like to retrieve the value of the following dl element to send it to a php file with an ajax request

```
<dl id="item" value="9">9</dl>
```

I tried all of the following code but none worked :/

```
var item = $('#item').attr('value');
var item = $('#item').val();
var item = $('#item').text();
var item = $('#item').html();
```

I don't know if it's relevant but here is the ajax request

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'myPhpFile.php',
    type: 'get',
    data: { 'item': item },
    success: function(data) {
        $('#myDiv').html(data);
    }
});
```

Also, on firebug there is no error, however the url doesn't have any parameter on it.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think a `value` attribute is valid for `<dl>` elements.

Comment: Open console and paste there this `$('#item').attr('value');` and see result. Or open sources to debug and set brakepoint on line, where is your `var item` starting.

Comment: If none of the answer posted here works, you need to add jquery source file in your page. I do that a lot :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks correct in the given example, so I would guess there's something else going on.  A few possibilities:

- Your selector (i.e., `#item`) is incorrect.
- Your code is being run before that element is added to the DOM
- The `item` variable is in a different scope from the AJAX request (i.e., it's value is `null` in the AJAX request's scope)
- The `item` variable is being overwritten before you make the request.

The easiest way to proceed is probably to step through with a debugger so you can watch both the DOM and the variables to see exactly what is happening at each step.

Comment: So after debugging it seem the correct answer is the second one. The #item element is loaded by another ajax request and my code is being run before it's added. So I put my function into the success part and now it works. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var item = $('#item').attr('value');
```

should be the correct choice.  I don't know why it's not working for you.

It's demonstrated [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesCurran/8QBy5/).

Answer (score 0):

Your Dl tag probably has DT tags inside. If you take the DL value, it won't return the values of its child elements
If I'm correct that you want to get child values, try this way

```
$('#dl dt:').val()
$('#dl dd:').val()
```